# How can this be shortened?

Tags: jquery, function, mouseover, jquery-hover, mouseout

Have several hotspots by ID.  The ID specific hotspots show an area (#ID-ed textarea) at mouseover and then hide the textareas at mouseout (note the CSS display:hidden was remarkably faster than hide).  Have about 50.  I have written this out verbosely - aka a function for every one.

Would like to learn a better, wiser,  efficient, and shorter way to do this.

```
    //// POP 1_1
$('#pop_01_01').hover(
    function() {
    $('#text_01_01.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
    },
    function() {
    $('#text_01_01.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
    }
);
//// POP 02_01
$('#pop_02_01').hover(
    function() {
    $('#text_02_01.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
    },
    function() {
    $('#text_02_01.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
    }
);
//// POP 02_01
$('#pop_02_02').hover(
    function() {
    $('#text_02_02.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
    },
    function() {
    $('#text_02_02.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
    }
);
//// POP 02_03
$('#pop_02_03').hover(
    function() {
    $('#text_02_03.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
    },
    function() {
    $('#text_02_03.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
    }
);
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, this is difficult to answer.

Comment: Sidenote: use `.hide()` instead of `.css({'display':'none'})`. It's shorter.

Comment: Appreciate the thought on hide(), however hide() is markedly slower and caused a blink.  Have tested this and verified it by others.  Just an FYI, hope this helps someone.

Comment: My apologies on the above comment regarding hide.  By shortening the code per jfriend00, the hide() is now hiding without the blink.  My original verbose code was much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Combine all the objects that have this behavior into one jQuery selector so they can all run the same code.
2. Remove the `textarea` from the selector since the ids are unqiue anyway so it isn't needed and should be faster without it.
3. Extract the id you want from the object's id that is being hovered and grab the ending characters so you can use it to create the other id you want.
4. Use `.hide()` instead of `.css({'display':'none'});` as a built-in shortcut.

Resulting Code:

```
$('#pop_01_01, #pop_02_01, #pop_02_02').hover(
    function() {$('#text_' + this.id.substr(-5)).fadeIn('fast');},
    function() {$('#text_' + this.id.substr(-5)).hide();}
);
```

Comment: The response from everyone was awesome - thank you all.  This method appears to be the tightest considering the naming conventions used for the clickable objects.  Thank You jfriend00.

Answer (score 1):

use a function like this:

```
function makehover(myid)
{
  $('#pop'+myid).hover(
      function() {
      $('#text'+myid+'.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
      },
      function() {
      $('#text'+myid+'.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
      }
  );
```

then call

```
 makehover('_01_01');
 makehover('_02_01');
 makehover('_02_02');
```

or call via jQuery

```
 $.each(['_01_01','_02_01','_02_02'],function (a,b) { makehover(b); });
```

or call via (1.6+ javascript )

```
 ['_01_01','_02_01','_02_02'].map(function (a) { makehover(a); return a; });
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the jquery way, consider that:

```
$.fn.makeHover = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this),
            $textarea = $el.find('textarea');

        $el.hover(
            function() {
                $textarea.fadeIn('fast');
            },
            function() {
                $textarea.hide();
            }
        );
    });
};

$('#pop_01_01, #pop_02_01, #pop_02_02, #pop_02_03').makeHover();
```

By the way, I'm also caching `$el` and `$textarea` to avoid going through the DOM all the time (for performance improvement).

Comment: how does caching $(this) improves perfomance? it's just making a copy of a reference...

Comment: @Pawel_W I was pretty sure it would improve performances to cache `$(this)` but tried to do some performances tests after your comment and it seems that you're right. http://jsperf.com/caching-this-jquery . Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to reference your items by class instead of id, and store the relevant part (01_01, 01_02, etc) in a data-id attribute instead of in the id.

```
HTML -
<div class="pop" data-id="_01_01"></div>
<div class="pop" data-id="_02_01"></div>
<div class="pop" data-id="_02_02"></div>

<textarea data-id="_01_01"></textarea>
<textarea data-id="_02_01"></textarea>
<textarea data-id="_02_02"></textarea>

//// All pops
$('.pop').hover(
    function(e) {
      var dataid = $(e.target).attr("data-id");
      $('textarea[data-id="'+dataid+'"]').fadeIn('fast');
    },
    function(e) {
      var dataid = $(e.target).attr("data-id");
      $('textarea[data-id="'+dataid+'"]').hide();
    }
);
```

Something like that should be able to nicely apply to all your elements, doesn't use a bunch of ugly unnecessary ids, and keeps your data clean and separate from your names.

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/fGLnB/

Comment: Really liking this technique as well.  Thank You iabw.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pop_01_01, #pop_02_01, #pop_02_02').hover(
    function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#text'+id.substring(3,id.length)).fadeIn('fast');          
    },
    function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#text'+id.substring(3,id.length)).css({'display':'none'});
    }
);
```

I have ommited ".textarea" class, because ID should be unique so there's no reason to use class additionally

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var hotspots = ['01_01','02_01','02_02'];   
hotspots.forEach(function(i) {
    $('#pop_' + i).hover(
        function() {
        $('#text_' + i + '.textarea').fadeIn('fast');          
        },
        function() {
        $('#text_' + i + '.textarea').css({'display':'none'});
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This won't actually work because `i` won't have the right value when the hover callback is called.  This would need a closure to freeze the right value of `i`.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00 thanks for pointing that out! I fixed the answer to an actually working one :)